# Perfect rounded corner?

Tags: bezier-curve

I wanted to do a curve like the image bellow with Illustrator CS6.
The problem is that I get corners all the time and even adding some anchor points I get my rectangle unaligned. What is the best way of achieving a smooth curve after a line? This comes from a rectangle and I didn't want to use rounded corners.

How I want it:

[image: Desired]

How I did it:

[image: How I got]

Best regards.

Comment: Place a circle and cut a half from, resize as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]What i assume you did is draw a line from **A** to **B**, then moved your curser to position **C** and pulled the anchors out to form the round part. 
Now there is two ways of getting a round curve

1. You pull the anchor at **C** further out so the curve is round. *But* that can be pretty hard to hit just the right point.

Thats why i prefer option

2. You already pull an anchor at **B** in the same direction as your line goes an then you get to **C**. With a little training that way it will be round.

[image]

I hope that helped. Sry for bad english.